# Designing a database for hotel menu

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational

I have a table called hotels and here is the schema

```
tables(type, id, name, description, menu, address)
```

I can easily store type, id, name, description and address. They are all strings and integers.

Consider there are about a 100 hotels each having different values.

But what about menu? How can i store that? A menu will be something like this:

```
Pasta : 10 euros
HamBurger : 5 euros
#similarly many items in the menu
```

Can someone tell me how to store it? Please try to explain in detail. I am not getting it at all. I tried storing menus in different table with id of hotel acting as foreign key but that makes me write a 100 tables just for menu.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you create a table for all possible menus("pasta", "burger", ..) a 2nd table link them to the hotels

Eg:
menus (menu_id, name, price)
hotels_menus (hotel_id, menu_id)

To find all dishes for a given hotel you retrieve them by "SELECT m.name, m.price FROM hotel_menus AS hm INNER JOIN menus AS m ON hm.hotel_id = [hotel_id] AND hm.menu_id = m.menu_id"

If price is different per hotel you move the price-field to the hotels_menus table.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you would need a category field also, like Appetizer, Main Course, etc.
You may even need more th

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create category, subcategory and foodname, price field in menu table. This may help. For example, in case of pasta your category will be food, subcategory will be veg non-veg and foodname will be pasta. You can follow this module incase of drinks too. According to need you can make your foodname field nullable too.